# Angular - How to change the url in without modifying the history

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, window.location

I would like to change the url of my page, but without changing the angular history state nor reloading the page.

Is this somehow possible ?

### Already tried

| Method | no history changes | not reloading | changing the url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `location.replaceState(url)` | not working | working | working |
| `router.navigateByUrl(url, {skipLocationChange: true, })` | working | not working | working |

### A bit of context

I'm adding the `/de` at the beginning of the url -> so from `/my-url` to `/de/my-url`.

But actually, the existing route is `/my-url` so for navigation through my app I've added a guard that.

1. Control the url
2. If it does have the `/de` remove it and `router.navigate(urlWithoutDe)`
3. Add it back again to visually see the `/de` *(or any other language like `/en`, `/fr`, ...)*
4. But when the user navigate back with the back button, the `guard` wont be triggered, so it will try to navigation to `/de/my-url` which does not exists..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try listening to the `beforeunload` event in your `app.component`, something like this:

```typescript
@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-root',
    ..
)}
class AppComponent {
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
    navigateToActualUrl() {
        // detect if the user is trying to load an invalid URL
        // not sure if location contains the "wrong" URL at this point
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeUnloadEvent

As a general note, Angular Guards will not be triggered when the user clicks on the back/forward buttons, you need to listen for this event.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Can you help me understand the reason why it should avoid you routing to the unexpected page ? (point 4 of my question)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's difficult to provide a more accurate answer without a stackblitz or some code snippets to understand exactly what you're doing. And I don't even understand your question here. Have you tried what I wrote above?

Comment: I like to "change the url of my page, without changing the angular history state nor reloading the page.". The code snippet is in the table of the already tried one. Stackblitz would be a bit hard to implement since I didn't worked it out. So for what I'm aware you're answer isn't really helping here